# vichuploader required upload

Tags: vichuploaderbundle, symfony5

I want to upload image with **VichUploaderBundle** inside **Collection** as a required field.

I use use **fileType** as a **new EmbeddedFile()** isinde my entity

## New form

If I don't provide file, validation tells me to add a file, expected behaviours.

## Edit form

If I've ever upload a file and don't provide one, the assertion tells me to add a file (again ?).

#### Test

I'll try to fix with this [trick](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/468#issuecomment-419436821) but:

1/ It doesn't work anymore

2/ I've missed something

I don't provide code because it is as the docs said.

If duplicate please forward me to.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score -1):

[Docs sa](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/form/vich_file_type.md)y to use a `'required' => false` option in your forms.

You can easily switch to a non-required (using `true` in same option) in form to add a file and keep `false` in form to edit file.